# Is there a way to detect when a visitor comes back to your page after opening a new window?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way, using JavaScript or jQuery, to detect when someone goes back to your page after opening a new window or tab?

I want to create a script that opens a new window or tab, and then does something when the user comes back to the page.

Thanks,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**yes**, there is. Using jQuery:

```
$(window).bind('focusout', function(){
    console.log('bye bye');
});

$(window).bind('focusin', function(){
    console.log('welcome back!');
});
```

**edit 1**

Using `alert()` was not the best idea there :p Changed to `console.log()` for demonstration.

**edit 2**

binding to `document` does not work crossbrowser, changed to `window`

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies, but that's not flawless. If you can use a server-side language, then you can track IP addresses.

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that they were closing the window and then re-opening it... ignore my answer, jAndy's is better in your case.